# How can $f(\frac{1}{z})$ not have a singularity at 0?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we have $f(z)$ with a Laurent Expansion with an infinite analytic part. Then $f(1/z)$ should have an infinite principal part of the form $\sum a_k (\frac{1}{z})^k$ and thus what appears to be an essential singularity at 0?

This seems too broad to be true, is there something wrong with it?

Comment: by definition a Laurent series is $f(z) = c + \sum_{n=1}^K a_n z^n +\sum_{n=1}^{M} b_n z^{-n}$ . if $K = M = \infty$ then we require that the two series both converge somewhere, i.e. in an annulus $C \le |z| \le R$. and in that case, the Laurent series $f(1/z) = c+\sum_{n=1}^K a_n z^{-n} +\sum_{n=1}^{M} b_n z^{n}$ converges in the the annulus $1/R \le |z| \le 1/C$. this way, you can see the symmetry between : ($K = \infty$) an essential singularity for $f(z)$ at $\infty$ and for $f(1/z)$ at $0$, and ($M= \infty$) an essential singularity for $f(1/z)$ at $\infty$ and for $f(z)$ at $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful about where the Laurent expansion is valid, but there is some truth to what you're saying.

If $f(z)$ is a meromorphic function on the Riemann sphere, then it is a rational function. So this tells us that "most" meromorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ do in fact have an essential singularity at $\infty$.

Comment: Can you help me see where I misstepped in my claim?

Comment: The Laurent expansion may only be valid in some annulus, rather than on all of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Ah, ok, I feel better.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this argument is that your Laurent series for $f(1/z)$ may not converge in any deleted neighborhood of $0$, so that you don't get $0$ as an isolated singularity.  For instance, if you take $f(z)=1/(1-z)$ with its expansion $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$, the expansion for $f(1/z)$ you get only converges for $|z|>1$.  But the function $f(1/z)$ is actually analytic at $0$.

In general, if your Laurent series for $f(z)$ converges on the annulus $r<|z|<R$, then the corresponding Laurent series for $f(1/z)$ will converge for $1/R<|z|<1/r$.  So if $R<\infty$ (i.e., the radius of convergence of the analytic part of the Laurent expansion is finite), then you cannot conclude that $f(1/z)$ has a singularity at $0$ (it might have a singularity, or it might be analytic, or it might not be defined in any deleted neighborhood of $0$ at all).  But if $R=\infty$ then your argument is correct, and you can conclude that $f(1/z)$ has an essential singularity at $0$.